# Use the delta method to find the distribution of $Z_n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $\overline{X}_n=\overline{X}$ the sample mean such that
>   $\sqrt{n}\overline{X}_n\rightarrow^D N(0,1)$ where $\rightarrow^D$
>   means converge in distribution. Use the delta method to find the
>   distribution of
>
> a)$Z_n=\sqrt{n}\overline{X}_n+A_n$ where $A_n=\frac{n}{n+2}$
>
> b)$Z_n=\sqrt{n}(e^{\overline{X_n}}-1)$
>
> c)$Z_n=n^{\frac{1}{4}}\overline{X_n}$

If I remember well the delta method says that
$$\sqrt{n}(g(T_n)-g(\theta))\rightarrow^D N(0,\sigma^2[g'(\theta)]^2)$$
for any statistic $T_n$ and function $g()$ of parameter $\theta$

a)Since $\sqrt{n}\overline{X_n}\rightarrow N(0,1)$ then $\sqrt{n}\overline{X_n}+A_n\rightarrow N(\frac{n}{n+2},1)$

I don't need to use the delta method in this case right?

How I can do the cases b) and c)?

I was looking again, maybe $n$ is parameter of $g$

Comment: Some clarification: The delta method is for finding the asymptotic distribution, but the question says "find the distribution of $Z_n$". And for a) you give a convergence (asymptotics) to a rhs depending on $n$ (finite sample).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) $A_n\to 1$ and $Z_n\xrightarrow{d}N(1,1)$.

b) Use the $\Delta$-method with $g(x)=e^x$ and $\theta=0$.

c) $Z_n=n^{-1/4}(n^{1/2}\bar X_n)=n^{-1/4}O_p(1)=o_p(1).$